# Перед машиной или за машиной?

Tags: предлоги

Недавно я попал в интересную ситуацию с таксистом в Калининграде, сам я из Москвы.

Я сказал таксисту "Остановитесь **перед** машиной [справа]", имея ввиду ситуацию, которую я проиллюстрировал на Рисунке 1. То есть под "**перед** машиной", я строго имел ввиду, то, чтобы машина к которой мы должны подъехать была **перед** нами.

Таксист в свою очередь поехал по траектории обозначенной на Рисунке 2. Я спросил его, - я же просил остановится **перед** машиной, а не **за** машиной. На что он мне ответил, - так я и остановился **перед** машиной, мы же встали **перед** ней. А вот если бы ты сказал "**за** ней", тогда я бы встал **сзади** неё.

При этом таксист как будто бы прав, ведь действительно "перед машиной" по идее должно быть именно перед ней.

Меня эта ситуация ввела в ступор, поскольку в Москве, таксистам я всегда говорю так как говорю и всегда находил в этом понимание. Встать **перед** [объект] - встать так, чтобы объект был перед нами; Встать **за** [объект] - встать так, чтобы объект был позади нас.

Кто прав и как вообще могла образоваться такая путаница?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикольно. Просто есть два смысла: "сразу до" (рис. 1, логично) и "впереди" (рис. 2, странно). Первого почему-то нет в базовых словарях, но оно есть в Викисловаре: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/перед

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну видимо вы не водите машину, дело в том, что в ПДД есть такое понятие как "опережение", которое означает что одна машина едет вперед другой по соседней, направленной в туже сторону, полосе дороги. Поэтому логично предположить что перед машиной, что её нужно определить. Хотя, слово перед контекстное и может означать до объекта, но с водителями машин с больной вероятностью это не сработает и 99% ответят вам, что вперед машиной = впереди машины, кроме того машина не женщина, чтобы её вперед пропускать.

Почему такое происходит? Думаю, тому есть две причины:

1. Движение авто регулируется инструкциями, в котором "перед" четко обозначает впереди другого движущегося объекта, например, машины, велосипеда, человека или др участника дорожного движения. А дом - это недвижимость, поэтому там с передом иначе: перед там где вход, скорее всего). (Кстати, странно, почему по-вашему перед машиной, это не перед дверью водителя авто?)
2. Край области объекта является одновременно его началом и концом, смотря как рассуждать: у сосиски два конца или два начала? Перед скорее всего относится к классу слов указывающих на границу объекта или некоего понятия. Если это связка объектов. то границей будет передний(последний), если это два разных объекта, то границей может быть перед другого. Поэтому во избежание путаницы лучше говорить "позади", или "сзади", или "за" машиной, или "до" машины. Иначе будут возникать каламбурные ситуации.

То есть не стоит винить водителя калининградского такси, за то, что он следует ПДД, а не правилам лингвистики.

Comment: +1 Действительно интересное наблюдение, я и машину вожу и ПДД знаю, но в обиходе в Москве водители всегда понимали (по крайней мере из собственного опыта), что перед = встать так чтобы объект был спереди.

Comment: @RoyalGoose знамо дело - москвичи ездят не по пдд) либо в москве все таксисты имеют высшее гуманитарное образование.